# Run-on sentences as a result of not only X but also Y inversion?

Tags: inversion, subject-auxiliary-inversion, run-on-sentences, negative-inversion, correlating-conjunctions

I have a question regarding the usage of 'not only... but also'.
**Query #1: When does 'not only...(but) (also)' inversion result in a run-on sentence?**

I present two sample sentences below - to me, they are either both correct or both incorrect. However, Grammarly prefers to like the second one, and has strong reservations about the first.

> S1: Not only are thieves able to divert cash from company bank accounts, they can also pilfer information *(Grammarly says I need to add in the 'but' here to prevent it from becoming a comma splice?)*

> S2: As criminal activity on the Internet becomes more and more sophisticated, not only are thieves able to divert cash from company bank accounts, they can also pilfer information. *(Grammarly likes this, and this is also presented as a correct sentence in an official question)*

Does the presence of 'As' as a subordinator have a hugely important role? I am unable to decipher how the addition of a dependent clause automatically prevents the run-on. Since, if the second part is an Independent Clause, it should be so even in the first sentence (S1)?*

As far as I can see, either the first part with 'not only' is an IC or it is not. In my opinion, it is not, as I feel I need something else to complete my sentence. So the conjunction 'but' (before the also) should be optional/unnecessary?

**Second**, I have seen sentences in the inverted form, where the 'but/but also/also' has been completely omitted from the second half. Reference - https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2009/04/22/not-only-but-also/

> Not only are there verbs with similar meanings and different past-tense forms, there are verbs with different meanings and the same past-tense forms. (Steven Pinker, Words and Rules)

> ...his application was not only refused by Bonn, it was hardly noticed and remained totally unsupported. (Hannah Arendt, Eichmann in Jerusalem)

Do these result in run-on sentences? Or are they considered acceptable because the first part isn't necessarily an Independent Clause?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You did ask a question the other day but you received NO answers, only comments. I'd say you got no answers because the question is off-topic. You're basically asking "is this correct"?

Comment: Dear @Astralbee - I have edited the question to make it closer to the specific topic of inversion, and whether the second half of the conjunction is required for it to not result in a run-on. Please suggest whether I need to make further edits.

Comment: It still lacks focus, you have more than one question in there. You need to read the site rules before posting, although I appreciate your first post here was migrated from another site with slightly different rules (they tend not to understand ours though and migrate a lot of poor quality questions)

Comment: Dear @Astralbee - I have further edited my query, and made it strictly related to the inversion within not only..but also.. parallel structure, and how/whether such structures result in a run-on. This is my query (the parallelism not so much but rather whether this structure may result in a run-on), and I cannot find a thread where this topic has been discussed wrt run-on sentences.